# Two Asp.Net Applications sending email through SMTP from same server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have an Asp.Net application running from AWS, and it has some process that require it to send e-mails automatically (the usual welcome, confirm email, etc...).

I was able to configure it and publish it. It works fine. But as the website enters "Production", I need to run a second application for testing purposes. I'm able to create it, and differentiate which one is being requested by the bindings in IIS.

The issue when both are up and running is that when I try to send an e-mail from the "Production" one, it works fine. But from the "Test" one, I get the following Exception:

```
[0:] {"$id":"1","Message":"Bad Request:System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 177.185.201.253:587\r
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)\r
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)\r
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.EndGetConnection(IAsyncResult result)\r
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r
   at Shappa.BackEnd.Helpers.EmailSender.<NewPhotoRequired>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\Andre\\Shappa\\Shappa.BackEnd-Dev\\Shappa.BackEnd\\Helpers\\EmailSender.cs:line 112\r
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r
   at Shappa.BackEnd.Controllers.AdminController.<PostPhotoReproved>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\Andre\\Shappa\\Shappa.BackEnd-Dev\\Shappa.BackEnd\\Controllers\\AdminController.cs:line 78"}
```

My Code to send email is pretty simple:

```
public async Task<bool> SendEmail(MailMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    var credential = Config.SMTPCredential;
                    smtp.Credentials = credential;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    //smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
#if DEBUG
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.kinghost.net";
#else
                    smtp.Host = "smtpi.kinghost.net";
#endif
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Port = 587;

                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this won't be a problem with your code. the IP in the error message proves that the `DEBUG` branch is used. both hosts ping fine. Maybe smtp.kinghost.net is not configured to process TLS/SSL connections?

Comment: You should never use `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You'll lose the original stack trace. Just use `throw;`. But then again, there's no point in doing a try/catch if the only thing you're going to do is throw the exception anyways. The try/catch might as well not be there. And since the only possible conclusions to your code are either `true` or an `exception`, there's no point in returning a boolean at all. Just make it return a Task.

Comment: Well, you are calling 2 different hosts `smtp` and `smtpi` so there _is_ a difference between them.

Comment: The smtp is the email server if the email is sent from Brazil, smtpi is for international. So, when I'm testing, i should send the email via smtp, as AWS is abroad, it should be smtpi. Otherwise it blocks.

Comment: regarding the Exception, I treat it where the SendEmail method was called. I do different stuff depending on the type of email.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Thanks dlatikay for your comment. It helped me find my stupid mistake.

177.185.201.253:587 this is an IP in Brazil, which meant I was deploying the application in DEBUG mode. Checking the options for publish, I was able to change it to Release. Now it works perfectly from both applications.